# Can't update description of listing with eBay API

Tags: perl, ebay-api

I'm trying to write a **Perl** script that will update our *eBay listings* descriptions without having to keep logging in (running across multiple marketplaces if proving tricky to keep stock levels, descriptions etc updated). Here is what I have so far:

```
 my $ebay = new Net::eBay( {
                              SiteLevel => 'prod',
                              DeveloperKey => 'x',
                              ApplicationKey => 'x',
                              CertificateKey => 'x',
                              Token => 'x',
                             } );

  $ebay->setDefaults( { API => 2, compatibility => 900  } );

my $new_desc = q|<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<p>We are proud to announce our first ever badge! With an easy-to-iron
on backing, fitting couldn't be any easier! We have designed the path to
 be a perfect addition to any piece of cosplay costume.&nbsp; Please do send
in the photos of it being used on your costumes, as we would love to
share.</p>
<p>The badge is 7 x 7 cm / 2 x 2 inches in size, and 2mm thi<br></p>|;

my $result = $ebay->submitRequest( "ReviseItem",
                      {
                       DetailLevel => "ReturnAll",
                       ErrorLevel => "1",
                       SiteId => "1",
                       Item => {
                         Description => \$new_desc,
                         ItemID => 253430606975
                       },
                       ItemID => 253430606975
                      }) || die;

 print "Result: " . Dumper( $result ) . "\n";
```

I get an error when running it though:

```
      'Errors' => [
                  {
                    'ShortMessage' => 'Return Policy Attribute Not Valid',
                    'ErrorClassification' => 'RequestError',
                    'ErrorCode' => '21920200',
                    'LongMessage' => 'Return Policy Attribute returnDescription Not Valid On This Site',
                    'SeverityCode' => 'Warning',
                    'ErrorParameters' => {
                                         'Value' => 'returnDescription',
                                         'ParamID' => '0'
                                       }
                  },
                  {
                    'ShortMessage' => 'Description is missing.',
                    'ErrorClassification' => 'RequestError',
                    'ErrorCode' => '106',
                    'SeverityCode' => 'Error',
                    'LongMessage' => 'A description is required.'
                  }
                ],
```

Am I misunderstanding what gets passed in? from what I can understand, you just pass in the params you want to change?

UPDATE: As suggested by Dave, I'm giving **Marketplace::Ebay** a go. Just testing by trying to select one of my items:

```
 my $ebay = Marketplace::Ebay->new(
                                  production => 1,
                                  site_id => 3,
                                  developer_key => 'xx',
                                  application_key => 'xx',
                                  certificate_key => 'xxx',
                                  token => 'xx',
                                  xsd_file => 'ebaySvc.xsd',
                                 );

my $res = $ebay->api_call('GetItem', { ItemID => 253430606975 });
print Dumper($res);
```

But I get some weird error:

> error: element `{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}GiftIcon' not
>   processed for {urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}GetItemResponse/Item at
>   /*/*[5]/*[6] $VAR1 = undef;

Any ideas?

Comment: [Net::Ebay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::eBay) hasn't been updated since 2012. There are a number of outstanding [problems with the code](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Net-eBay) (some going back thirteen years - and some mentioning problems with schema updates. All in all, I'd be very wary about using this module.

Comment: Are you sure you should have `Item` key? Judging by the documentation (bad as it is) `Description` should be on the top-level, not inside `Item`.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks. Do you know of a more up to date module?

Comment: @StefanBecker I'm pretty sure thats right. As you said, the documentation is pretty outdated. It seems to work otherwise (i tried it with a **getItem** request, and it grabbed it all fine)

Comment: Looking more at it- seems to be an issue with eBay's API themselves. A problem thats been around a while :/ https://ebay.to/2NpkXTe

Comment: @AndrewNewby: [Marketplace::Ebay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marketplace::Ebay) looks better-maintained. I haven't used any of them though, so I can't really give recommendations.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks for that - will have a play and see if I can get it going :) (I have a feeling its still going to give that error message though, as it seems to be a general eBay API issue)

Comment: @DaveCross I've just given Marketplace::Ebay a go, but it gives an error (even trying to select an item - which I could manage fine on the other module). Please see the question that I've updated. Any ideas what it means? Gibberish to me!

Comment: @AndrewNewby: Nope. Gibberish to me too. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @DaveCross no worries. I'll keep digging with the other module. It seems to be an error with eBays API itself (lots of people complaining about it, but goes back almost a year :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha - got it! The issue seemed to be around the way the HTML was being passed along. If I put it inside a `CDATA` tag, it works fine:

```
my $new_desc = q|<![CDATA[
some html etc here
]]>|;

my $result = $ebay->submitRequest( "ReviseItem",
                      {
                       DetailLevel => "ReturnAll",
                       ErrorLevel => "1",
                       SiteId => "1",
                       Item => {
                         Description => $new_desc,
                         ItemID => 253430606975
                       },
                       ItemID => 253430606975
                      }) || die;
```

...and updates perfectly